# Generic "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" Failure

Tags: paypal

I've just switched from using normal "plain text" PayPal buttons to encrypted buttons (both home-made as they need to be dynamic). The plain ones worked fine but I'm running into issues with the Encrypted version. Paypal simply fails with the generic "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" message and provides no further information.

The information I'm posting is...

```
cert_id=<certificateID>
business=<merchantID>
return=<returnURL>
cancel_return=<returnURL>
notify_url=<ipnURL>
cn=Email Address Needed
lc=GB
currency_code=GBP
button_subtype=services
no_note=0
no_shipping=1
rm=1
charset=utf-8
item_name=<productName>
item_number=<productID>
amount=<value>
```

Everything in <> is removed for security reasons at this point, but that should give you some idea of what is being encrypted then posted.

The form is simple and is submitted by a jQuery AJAX call (to cut down on the -massive- amount of data that the encrypted buttons add to the page)...

```
<form id='igp-<prodID>' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick' />
    <input type='hidden' name='encrypted' value='{$paypalData}' />
</form>
```

PayPal's documentation is rather randomly spread about in terms of what you need to do here, but I can't see anything I'm missing.

If I replace a letter in the cert_id then it still fails with the same message (rather than telling me it couldn't decrypt the data) which gives the impression it's not even getting that far.

Any ideas?

**EDIT / Update:**
It appears the failure is actually "We were unable to decrypt the certificate id." (shows up when using the Sandbox). The code sent to OpenSSL looks sane (correct '=' matched values).

The code for OpenSSL that I'm using is...

```
 $opensslOutput = trim(shell_exec("export RANDFILE='system/.rnd'; (openssl smime -sign -signer {$keystoreCert} -inkey {$keystoreKey} -outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n{$paypalData}\n_EOF_\n) | openssl smime -encrypt -des3 -outform pem -binary {$paypalCert}"));
```

Which in turn produces a large PCK7Z block and no errors from OpenSSL. So this begs the question, what may Paypal be failing on here? Does the above code no-longer produce a signed block that Paypal likes?

Comment: FWIW this error is now PERVASIVE and is not necessarily restricted to encrypted payments. Many forum entries have identified a possible browser problem (works on Safari, but not Chrome?) and the overall impression is that it's due to Paypal's design overhaul. Either way, it is affecting payments, which can't be good for them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround and for a superior integration, I would recommend using the Express Checkout API instead.

It can do everything standard PayPal buttons can do and more, and works will all PayPal accounts that can accept money with standard buttons.

Have you tried Express Checkout?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php

The main difference to note is that, by default, EC requires buyers to sign in or create a PayPal account as they are checking out.  You can enable the exact same guest checkout functionality as standard by adding SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole to your initial SetExpressCheckout API call.

Another difference to note is that with EC, the customer will always return to your site before the payment is completed.  This is a good thing, as you will have the opportunity to either present the customer with an order review page and update any totals, or simply execute the payment immediately, get an immediate API response, and immediately thank or ask the customer to try again.

Basically, EC is better in *every single* respect.  You just need to be able to write HTTPS API calls from your server to PayPal.

Comment: I had noticed this mentioned but couldn't see any simple example implementations anywhere. The items are all going to be single item "Buy now" style setups so a full-blown cart isn't needed.


The walkthrough on the Paypal site seems to be massive overkill compared to a single post submission that I was trying to use.

Comment: To add further to this, it appears that Express Checkout also requires the use of their SDK which I would rather avoid as well as I'm trying to keep this small and self-contained (and I don't want to run into 3rd party compatibility issues with PHP versions going forward either).

Comment: Express Checkout does not require any SDK, that is optional.

If your needs are that simple, why are you not using PayPal's hosted buttons?  What kind of dynamic-ness do you need? And what are your security needs for going with encrypted buttons?

Comment: There are hundreds of products, each priced differently so manually creating buttons for every product would take ages compared to simply sending through the product name, ID and price through via a post as shown above.

Not encrypting the post data seems like a bad idea with Paypal as it can simply be changed to anything via the developer tools in browsers which whilst incredibly unlikely is still a risk.

I'm not sure how Express Checkout would work without the SDK because their SDK contains all the functions they use during the examples to actually send the data to Paypal.

Comment: Adding more to this - their documentation is also all over the place. The "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox" you linked to tells you you need to use an SDK that doesn't even include the functions you need. Additionally when you try and download that SDK it tells you it's deprecated and to use the new one, which then tells you lots of features aren't supported yet.

Comment: Try the third link.  There is no /need/ for an SDK, the EC API is quite easily integrated with HTTPS API calls.

Comment: I disagree with "easily". Lots of the documentation is contradictory, misses key information or simply references things that don't exist. I did finally find one site with examples that look easily enough to reverse engineer into something useful, hopefully others will find it useful too - http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php